# Align Absolutely Positioned Sticky Element to div inside Sibling?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors

Say I have the following setup of a blogpost:

```html
    <div>
        <div> //this div has some margin left & right, so the blog post is centered
            <div>Title</div>
            <div>Body</div>
        </div>

        <ContainerAbsolute> //inside the right margin, i absolutely position this container & the sticky side bar inside it.
            <StickySideBar />
        </ContainerAbsolute>
    </div>
```

I want my StickySideBar to be on the right side and go down along the blog post. I use `position:sticky` on it. I've put it into a container, that is positioned absolutely, and that stretches down the whole page (`height: 100%`). Now that works. But now I'd like my StickySideBar to be stuck to the level where my Text begins, not the very top. I can do `top: 500px` and things like that, to approximate this, but how can I align it perfectly to the `Body` div?

Comment: What about moving it to the body div? And placing the text in a div?

Comment: I could do that, but in my setup those margins actually come from a component up way higher in the hierarchy, so I was looking for a solution that allows me to keep the Container as a Sibling to the Blogpost. Not possible at all?